# W3schools login form not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, forms

I have recently started learning how to style forms and came across this particular form on w3schools. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_login_form.asp.

I have pasted the same code that the website tells me to and it will not display correctly. Here is the code provided from the website.

Html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form action="action_page.php">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
            <img src="images/avatar.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

            <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

            <button type="submit">Login</button>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
            <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
            <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Bordered form */
form {
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
}

/* Full-width inputs */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Add a hover effect for buttons */
button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Extra style for the cancel button (red) */
.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Center the avatar image inside this container */
.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}

/* Avatar image */
img.avatar {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* Add padding to containers */
.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

/* The "Forgot password" text */
span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

The link provided will show what the desired output looks like and this is the output that I get from running this code. [image: current output]

I have double-checked to make sure there are no extra tags inserted and everything is correct so I cannot see what could be causing this.

Comment: Looks like your CSS file is not being loaded. Your path to the file is probably not correct. Check the developer tools.

Comment: hello, Bram. I do have another HTML file which is using this same style sheet with stylings for navigation bars and the like, I took those out for the purpose of this question to focus solely on the code that the website gives. the way i reference the css file in that HTML file is the same as this one and it works flawlessly

Comment: Do you have any errors or notices in your dev tools if you reload the page? open your devtools by pressing F12.

Comment: Hi, Kevin. I did not know about that Dev tools function. I opened Dev tools and in the console, it says 0 errors. I'm assuming that's what you were referring to?

Comment: Okay so, I am not sure what happened but it appears to have just worked after I refreshed the page with dev tools open... I can't really supply an answer when I don't even know what I did. Anyway, it's fixed, thanks for the dev tools tip!

Comment: Not sure but maybe an earlier copy of one of your files was cached.  Dev tools disables cache and pulls fresh copies each request.

Comment: Probably cache, indeed.

Comment: Oh? that makes sense then. Thanks for all the help guys, much appreciated.